# remove document from mongodb collection with curl

Tags: mongodb, curl

I want to remove document from mongodb collection in script linux(with curl).
like elastic commands ::

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/my-index-000001/_search?pretty"
```

Comment: Not possible, MongoDB has no HTTP service (in very early release of MongoDB it was existing though). You need to write a script (e.g. Node.js) on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

AS @Wernfried mentioned mongoDB do not provide HTTP service so you cannot use curl  , however you can do something like this from your linux shell script:

```
echo 'db.getCollection("myCollection").remove({_id:"documentIdforRemoval"})'| mongo --quiet --host myDBhost --port myDBport myDB --AuthenticationDatabase=admin -u myuser -p mypass
```